# ELI5 Including an npm package

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm

I understand including packages in an app using a framework such as Angular 2, but I'm lost when it comes to including a package into static, fully custom websites.  For example:

- I create the package.json file, great.
- I install and --save the package into the package.json file, great.

Now what?  For Javascript packages it typically says to write the `require('');` line or for CSS packages it might say to include the `@import('');`, but where?

Typically I'm just running a static site with a /css and /js folder.  Do I insert the require() or import() in the main JS or CSS file?  If so, how does it know to read into the /node_modules folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options, and the list will likely change as time goes on and new tools are created. Here are a few of your current options:

## 1. Reference the javascript file in your HTML

This is the most basic option. Just add this to your HTML file: `<script src="node_modules/package/package.min.js"></script>`. It's not great because you need to manually add each file to your HTML and make sure to add them in the right order (in case some packages have dependencies). It also means you have to include your whole `node_modules` folder in your website, which you probably don't want to do.

There's no `require('')` if you use this option. You just have to hope that the packages expose a variable on the global namespace.

## 2. Use a tool like `gulp` or `webpack` to bundle your references

I recommend Webpack because it comes out-of-the-box with support for import statements. See the [getting started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) guide. You could also use gulp, but then you would need a plugin like `gulp-browserify` to make the imports work.

There are a few ways to import modules. You probably want to use `import` instead of `require`. For simple modules:

`import _ from 'lodash'`

For more complex modules like Angular (`npm install @angular/core`):

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

To use Webpack, run:

```
npm install --global webpack
webpack app/index.js dist/bundle.js
```

where `app/index.js` is your entry point, and `dist/bundle.js` is the output file that webpack will build. Any files imported by `index.js` will be included in the output file. Then your HTML file should reference `dist/bundle.js`.